# SQL query optimization for select query over IN query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one view, i want to add pagination logic on this view. There are over 1.5 million records. It took longer time to get result if for my where condition that select only specific records mapped with one Id.
I am thinking of getting only those mapped records from main table and then select only those records from view, will this faster?

```
Select top 10 col1, col2, col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col4 desc) from vMyView where someid=1
```

Then

```
Select top 10 col1, col2, col3 from vMyView where col1 in (Select col1 from tMyTable where someid=1)
```

FYI I am not expert

Comment: Depends on how that `vMyView` is built and what indexes exist on that views underlying tables (as well as indexes on `tMyTable`). My guess is that adding in MORE logic to your SQL isn't going to make it faster.

Comment: Well, and on top of that IN is notoriously slow because the query optimizer does not generate statisticsi information for the number of parameters. Once you hit a number of them (10, 20?) it is always better to use a temporary table variable, load the values in them and use join - because that table variable actually DOES get statistics generated if you define it propertly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming typical cardinality, I tend to write it more like this:

```
select top 10 col1, col2, col3 
from vMyView v
inner join tMyTable t ON t.col1 = v.col1
WHERE t.someid = 1
```

However, if it's possible to match more than one row in `tMyTable` for each `col1` value in `vMyView`, this could possibly result in duplicating rows from `vMyView`. If duplicating rows is possible, a solution based on `row_number()` is typically the fastest option.

---

> i want to add pagination logic on this view

As for paging, you should look into [`OFFSET/FETCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) syntax, rather than `TOP n`.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM vMyView v
ORDER BY <need an order by clause for paging to work>
OFFSET <pagenumber * pagesize> FETCH NEXT <pagesize> ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I got some work around on this with the help of seniors, thanks everyone for help. Appreciated.